# Create tunnel through an open SFTP connection?

Tags: ssh, sftp, tunnel

I have a remote PC (behind NAT and firewall) set up to create a reverse SSH tunnel to my home PC/server (DMZed).  Unfortunately, the tunnel hasn't been working lately.  *Fortunately* -- I think -- the remote PC currently has an SFTP session open to the local one.

My question is, can I create a tunnel *back* to the remote PC through that session, say by "piggybacking" on the established connection?  Or am I SOL until I can physically get in to restore the reverse tunnel on the remote PC?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much your only hope, I think, is if your SFTP session gives you access to create a cron job, or otherwise create a script that can be run without local access.  Then you could drop a script in place that would initiate an SSH connection.

Comment: Thanks, but the _remote_ PC is the SFTP client, downloading from the _local_ server.  I thought about dropping a script into the folder, but then realized there's no way to make the remote PC run it... without SSH access.  I'll just have to check on it tomorrow, and hopefully I can fix the reverse tunnel and this question will be moot. I'll keep your suggestion in mind for the future, though!